# How to make ipython default when you run python if ipython is installed?

Tags: python, ipython

I am looking for a make bash profile trick to make `ipython` default when you run python from the command line, obvioulsly without damaging normal python script executon.

Is this possible, how?

Answer (score 3):

Create an alias in the `.bashrc` file:

```
alias python='ipython'
```

Comment: Are python and ipython interchangeable when running scripts?

Comment: @ReyCharles `IPython` is quite stable now, but I'd prefer python over IPython for running scripts. IPython is really good for interactive tasks.

Answer (score 0):

possible , may be , dangerous also...
i think that's not a good idea, but, if you are on linux ,  you can use alias:

```
alias python="ipython"
```

put it , in your ~/.bash_rc for exemple

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/reference.html#ipython-as-your-default-python-environment) the recommended approach from the IPython documentation. I don't have any opinion on running scripts using this though.